# Training YOLOv3 with different format dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo

Training YOLOv3 with own dataset, but annotation/label XML file in a different format.

The given labeled dataset have a more complicated format, with rotation angles and contour coordinations. However, I trained with the given labeled dataset and resulted a loss=9.6 model, but this model detected nothing. Epoch=50, Batch=1, dataset has 1300 images.
The model comes from: https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3

```
#This is given format
<parking id="pucpr">
  <space id="1" occupied="0">
    <rotatedRect>
      <center x="300" y="207" />
      <size w="55" h="32" />
      <angle d="-74" />
    </rotatedRect>
    <contour>
      <point x="278" y="230" />
      <point x="290" y="186" />
      <point x="324" y="185" />
      <point x="308" y="230" />
    </contour>
  </space>

#This is re
quired format
<annotation>
    <folder>test</folder>
    <filename>2012-09-12_07_18_22.jpg</filename>
    <path>C:/Users/Desktop/test/2012-09-12_07_18_22.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1280</width>
        <height>720</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>occupied</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>359</xmin>
            <ymin>416</ymin>
            <xmax>407</xmax>
            <ymax>479</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

What should I do to the labeled the dataset? Is my result means the dataset is fitted in YOLOv3 but required more configurations on settings?`enter code here`

Comment: what is `x` and `y` in `contour`? is it the 4 points bounding box coordinates?

Comment: @gameon67 Yes, this is four point contour information, instead of normal rectangle coordinates.

Comment: can I see your annotated data sample with image?

Comment: @gameon67 sample labeled image can be found in this paper, Fig 4. http://www.inf.ufpr.br/lesoliveira/download/ESWA2015.pdf

Comment: I couldn't find contour in that paper tho. And in your code above, the required format is the output format that you want?

Comment: @gameon67 I mean, these are annotation file that required by YOLOv3 in keras, but the given annotation format is different from the required annotation format. The given format is a rectangle with a rotation angle and four points on each edge, the required the format just center coordinates and xy_max/min.

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution to this? Facing the same issue